# Mixpanel — delete user with all past data

Tags: mixpanel

I'm working on adding Mixpanel for my project. After logging some crappy data at first, I deleted the user from Mixpanel, deleted it from my test database, and gone through registration again.

However, since I used DeviceUDID as Mixpanel's distinct id, it was the same for the new user — and when I opened Mixpanel, I saw the deleted user ressurected, with all old data and events in his profile.

How can I delete this old user forever?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can delete a user permanently from Mixpanel. Here is how:

```
{
    "$token": "YOUR_TOKEN",
    "$distinct_id": "DISTINCT_ID_TO_REMOVE",
    "$delete": ""
}
```

You have to encode it in Base64 (e.g. with this tool: https://www.base64encode.org/) and append the base64-encoded data as url parameter to http://api.mixpanel.com/engage/

The example would look like this: http://api.mixpanel.com/engage/?data=ew0KICAgICIkdG9rZW4iOiAiWU9VUl9UT0tFTiIsDQogICAgIiRkaXN0aW5jdF9pZCI6ICJESVNUSU5DVF9JRF9UT19SRU1PVkUiLA0KICAgICIkZGVsZXRlIjogIiINCn0=

Comment: Are you sure that when you create a new user with the same disctinct_id afterwards, all the data of the old user won't be resurrected in it's place? Because that's what happened to me

Comment: Yes, all user data will be permanently deleted. But of course, some properties will be set automatically through by client side APIs, which might be the same as before - like city or region.